# How to load mysql dump to hsqldb database?

Tags: mysql, groovy, migration, hsqldb

I have a sql file that creates a database in mysql:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`machine`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`machine` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Now I would like to load this file into hsqldb 2 database. What do I need to change in the mysql dump to load the data into hsqldb?

Currently I use this code (groovy) to execute the sql file:

```
def embeddedDbSettings = [url:'jdbc:hsqldb:file:mydb', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'];
sql =  Sql.newInstance(embeddedDb);
sql.executeInsert new File("./sql/create_database.sql").text;
```

and all the time I got this crypting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: unknown token
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.executeInsert(Sql.java:1440)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at de.hpi.ecir.eval_script.Convert2Excel.main(Convert2Excel.groovy:37)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unknown token
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Remove all SET lines
2. Change a line with command which creates a database to: `CREATE SCHEMA mydb AUTHORIZATION DBA`
3. Remove all `if not exists` - hsqldb does not support this command
4. Remove all commends (not neccesary but needed for the code you find in this post)
5. Remove all `
6. Replace TINYINT (mysql equivalent for boolean) by boolean
7. Execute each command separately:

   ```
   String[] commands = new File("./sql/create_database.sql").text.split(";");

   for(String command: commands)
   {

    // new line is a delimiter in hsqldb

     sql.execute command.replace("\n", " ");
   }

   // remember to call shutdown otherwise hsqldb will not save your data
   sql.execute "SHUTDOWN"
   sql.close();
   ```

Comment: Afaik, TINYINT represents an 8-bit variable (range 0-255), not a boolean.

Answer (score 7):

You also have to :

- replace "AUTO_INCREMENT" in CREATE_TABLE by "GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY"
- replace "int" by "integer"
- move "default" statement in column creation for example :

from this :

```
CT_CLIENT integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

to this :

```
CT_CLIENT integer DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL ,
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run each command separately, hsqldb works fine if you run the scripts all at once, as long as all your tokens are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using IntelliJ IDEA :

1. In the database tab, add a connection to your database (MySQL in this case)
2. Right-click on desired database and click on "Copy DDL".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by relying on [RazorSQL](https://razorsql.com). It is not for free, but with the evaluation version you have enough for performing the conversion from MySQL to HSQLDB. It also supports other DB conversions.

The only problem I detected during the conversion was the primary keys. So basically, the following generated code excerpt would not run for me:

```
CREATE TABLE items_fractions (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fraction_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I had to remove the IDENTITY bit.