# Is it possible to use mysql dump for populating hsqldb database?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, junit, hsqldb

I'm trying to duplicate my mysql tables for hsqldb in order to run some unit tests in my JPA / Hibernate project.

There are only two tables at the moment, but I can't get neither created in hsqldb. I used the example code from Spring documentation to run a schema.sql script before the test cases:

```
db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addDefaultScripts().build();
```

But it always fails with "Unexpected token" exceptions with the token ranging from "DATABASE" to "(".

Is there a straight forward way of converting the mysql dump into something that hsqldb would understand? Or should I populate the test database some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked many years with HSQL and MySQL database and there's no tool that I know that converts a MySQL dump into a hsqldb script. I see two solutions here:

1. Make a script or a program that converts MySQL dumps to hsqldb script. You can follow the list of steps to do in this post:
   [How to load mysql dump to hsqldb database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811906/how-to-load-mysql-dump-to-hsqldb-database)
   Use BOTH responses
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/3813164/891479
   and
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791340/891479
   as the first one is not complete.
2. Make a small program that connects to both DB, load your MySQL tables into objects and fill your hsqldb.

We always used the first solution, it's probably the easiest one.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Meanwhile, I found DBUnit and its xml definitions to be sufficient for now, instead of trying to duplicate the schema.